# GWT align image and text

Tags: image, gwt, alignment

Using GWT I am trying to create a row of images with text centered below them.  There isn't much detail on GWT online so I'm having a difficult time.  The image should also be a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this layout using standard HTML and CSS. The most obvious solution is to use floating divs which contain an image and its text, with "text-align: center" rule applied to the div.

In GWT you can achieve this either through a Ui:Binder, or, if the images are dynamic, by creating a custom widget to represent each image with its text.

The alternative solution is to use a HorizontalPanel widget and add images and text inside, which is an equivalent of using a table to achieve your desired layout. This solution is not responsive, though.